# Using CHARINDEX positions to determine data to parse

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to parse data from a table that was loaded from an old database migration, where the data is one long string of data. It starts and ends with certain parameters and based on those parameters I am trying to separate the data into multiple columns.

Data currently looks like this:

```
MT410    YNYAasdflk56534534  BATCH X00ABC
MT500    ASDFKJAS adfl fjkd asdf dj RMS
```

I have been able to get the first part and the last part, but where I struggle is if the last part is a certain thing I need to get the 2nd to last part, then everything in between.  If it's another way I need the first part the last part and everything in between as such:

```
first_part     mid_part                    2nd_last_part       last_part
MT410        YNYAasdflk56534534            BATCH                X00ABC
MT500        ASDFKJAS adfl fjkd asdf dj    <blank>              RMS
```

I am trying to understand how I can use the positions within the CHARINDEX to tell a substring where to start and end from:
This is the code I currently have to get the first part and last part:

```
select cnsmr_accnt_ar_mssg_txt, LEFT(cnsmr_accnt_ar_mssg_txt, CHARINDEX(' ', cnsmr_accnt_ar_mssg_txt) - 1) as txt_frst_space,

REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(cnsmr_accnt_ar_mssg_txt), CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(cnsmr_accnt_ar_mssg_txt))-1)) as txt_lst_space,

CHARINDEX(' ', cnsmr_accnt_ar_mssg_txt) as first_space_pos,

REVERSE(CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(cnsmr_accnt_ar_mssg_txt))) as last_Space_post,

SUBSTRING(cnsmr_accnt_ar_mssg_txt, CHARINDEX(' ', cnsmr_accnt_ar_mssg_txt), 10)  as mid_string
from #table_name
```

I can get it to give me the first part and the last part, and the positions of the first space and the first space before the last part, but I can't figure out how to get the middle section to parse out.  There can be any number of spaces in the middle so I need to be able to tell it based on certain conditions, which position to start with.

Comment: CHARINDEX has support for start position parameter, you can use it to "advance" your search. Usually it gets a bit messy when you want to have nested CHARINDEXes to look for things,but that's life.